# Parse JSON String without array name with GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am getting a JSON String `{"status":208,"routes":[1,9,3]}` from a Jersey project in my Android app. The JSON String has no flag name for it. Is it possibale to parse it with  GSON libarary ?  I am just actually intressted just in the ArrayList `routes` values in it. I have done the following but I dont have a List to get. How can I do that with Gson?

doInbackground method:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");

            }

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            StopsJSONList obj = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), StopsJSONList.class);
            List<StopsJSON> stopsjson = obj.getStopsList();
            Iterator<StopsJSON> iterator = stopsjson.iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                StopsJSON  stopsElement = (StopsJSON) iterator.next();
                ArrayList<Integer> routeList = stopsElement.getRoute();

            }
```

StopsList class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class StopsJSONList {
    private ArrayList<StopsJSON> stops;

    public ArrayList<StopsJSON> getStopsList() {
        return stops;
    }

    public void setStopsList(ArrayList<StopsJSON> stopsList) {
        this.stops = stopsList;
    }
}
```

StopsJSON:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StopsJSON {
    private int status;
    private ArrayList<Integer> route ;


    public StopsJSON(int status, ArrayList<Integer> route) {
        //super();
        this.status = status;
        this.route = route;
    }
    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public ArrayList<Integer> getRoute() {
        return route;
    }
    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public void setRoute(ArrayList<Integer> route) {
        this.route = route;
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the `route` attribute in `StopsJSON` class doesn't match the `routes` field in the json structure. To solve the problem, you can either change the `StopsJSON` class's attribute to `routes` or add an annotation like so

```
@SerializedName("routes")
private ArrayList<Integer> route ;
```

This is an easy way on how to do it:

*Create class `StopsJSON` as follow*

```
class StopsJSON {
    private int status;
    private ArrayList<Integer> routes;

    public StopsJSON(int status, ArrayList<Integer> route) {
        // super();
        this.status = status;
        this.routes = route;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getRoutes() {
        return routes;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public void setRoutes(ArrayList<Integer> routes) {
        this.routes = routes;
    }

}
```

*Use Gson API to convert json String to a `StopsJSON` object*

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
StopsJSON data = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), StopsJSON.class);
```

*Get your `routes`*

```
ArrayList<Integer> routes = data.getRoutes();
System.out.println(routes);
```

*Output:*

```
[1, 9, 3]
```